# How would I resize multiple images in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I was setting up this list where it had images (images are sprites) loaded in. I was trying to create this loop where it would rescale all the images inside this list.

```
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('Moving1.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving2.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving3.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving4.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving5.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving6.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving7.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving8.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving9.png')]
walkRight = []
for i in walkLeft:
    walkRight.append(pygame.transform.flip(i, True, False))

for x in walkLeft:
    pygame.transform.smoothscale(x,(372, 493))
```

I was expecting the image size to be resized, but instead, it just stayed the same and I was not sure with what to do.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about pygame itself, as I've never used it, but I think the issue is that `pygame.transform.smoothscale()` isn't *transformative* - it doesn't change the `x` you're feeding it, but rather outputs a changed version without modifying the original. You can see similar behavior in `pygame.transform.flip(i, True, False))` - every iteration, it produces a modified copy of `i`, which you append to `walkRight`, but it isn't changing the `i` you started with.

The way you'd probably want to go about this is by iterating *by index* instead of *by element*, and actually replacing elements as you go:

```
for i in range(len(walkLeft)):
    walkLeft[i] = pygame.transform.smoothscale(x, (372, 493))
```

You could alternatively skip a step and simply recreate the entire list using list comprehensions, which would make your script more idiomatic overall:

```
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('Moving1.png'), ...]
walkRight = [pygame.transform.flip(x, True, False) for x in walkLeft]
walkLeft = [pygame.transform.smoothscale(x, (372, 493)) for x in walkLeft]
```

Answer (score 1):

[`pygame.transform.smoothscale()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale) can't process lists.
The method scales an image which is passed by parameter and returns a new, scaled image by the return value. The return value hast be reassigned to the list.

You have to do it in a loop:

Either:

```py
for i in range(len(walkLeft)):
    walkLeft[i] = pygame.transform.smoothscale(walkLeft[i], (372, 493))
```

or in one line:

```py
walkLeft = [pygame.transform.smoothscale(x, (372, 493)) for x in walkLeft]
```

Answer (score 0):

[pygame.transform.smoothscale](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale) returns a new object, so you need to return it to a value:

```
for x in range(len(walkLeft)):
    walkLeft[x] = pygame.transform.smoothscale(x,(372, 493))
```

Comment: In your solution `x` is an integer - `.smoothscale()` does not take an integer for its first argument. If you need an item and its index you can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).